# Convert fetched blob data to object and return it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a function in react to fetch a `.csv` file stored in S3, then read the blob in it, convert it to and object and return it:

```
import { Storage } from "aws-amplify";
import Papa from "papaparse";



const GetDataFromS3 = (pathToFile) => {
  Storage.get(pathToFile, { download: true, expires: 10 })
    .then((result) => {
      var blob = new Blob([result.Body], {
         type: "text/csv",
      });
      blob.text().then(async (data) => {
        const obj = await Papa.parse(data, { header: true });

        return obj;
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
export default GetDataFromS3;
```

The problem is that when I call this function in the `useEffect` of another component in which I want to use the data fetched, the data is `undefined`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const data = await GetDataFromS3("AirPassengers.csv");
      await console.log(data); //logs undefined
      await setData(data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

What am I doing wrong, and perhaps is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Your `GetDataFromS3` does not `return` anything, that's why.

Comment: Ohh that's the point! How can I modify the function to actually return what I want to return?

Comment: Just put a `return` in front of the promise chain you're creating, and a `return` on the inner promise chain inside the `then` callback. I'd also recommend to remove the `.catch((err) => console.log(err))` though and put it on the `fetchData()` call in the effect instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bergi... I got messed up with all those promise chains. It is a goof practice in general what I did?

Answer (score 0):

For one, you're just ignoring all errors in `GetDataFromS3`, which is bad form.

Secondly, I think the Blob conversion is unnecessary; you should be able to get by with just

```
async function getDataFromS3(pathToFile) {
  const result = await Storage.get(pathToFile, { download: true, expires: 10 });
  const obj = await Papa.parse(result.Body, { header: true });
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! Although I am still getting an issue that if I log the result from the component in which I want to consume the data  I get just a fulfilled promise, while the data itself is undefined

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(result.Body)` or similar to see what's happening there?

Comment: I mean, log it in that function, before doing the `Papa.parse` bit. This is to figure out whether or not it's just Papa failing to parse things...

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. It seems Papa has some issue parsing it, since logging `const result = await Storage.get(pathToFile, { download: true, expires: 10 });` gives the expected result.